# How can I use an IIFE script in a Deno program?

Tags: javascript, module, deno

We have a library of JS that currently must target ES3 because a production product uses a tool with an older JS engine, and this is non-negotiable. But I need to be able to use this library in Deno, and I can't convert it to ES modules. The library is currently using function-closure modules, ala Crockford, where every source is a single constructor function like this:

```
function ModuleName() { 
"use strict";
...
}
```

and then the module is consumed with `let mod=new ModuleName();`.

Is there any way I can use these in deno? I don't care how, exactly -- I can load the script and `eval` it if necessary, but it would be nice to just use some form of import.

I've tried loading the script file and using `eval` and using `Function`, in various forms, and about every variation of `import` documented. I've scoured the Deno docs and tried every search I can think of. All to no avail.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: "*I can't convert it to ES modules*" - can't you change the build process? Use modern syntax, emit ES3-targeting modules for production, emit TypeScript modules for Deno.

Comment: Using the `Function` constructor (like `Function(source + '\n return new moduleName;')()`) should work. Can you show us what exactly you tried and how it didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key was to wrap the source file with `Function(return (+ ... +);)()` to get a reference to the module constructor function, which can then be constructed. I'm open to better ideas, but this works for my case.

```
function createModule(pthORurl, ...args) {
    try {
        let mod = Function("return ("+Deno.readTextFileSync(pthORurl)+");")();
        if(typeof(mod)!=="function") { throw Error("Loaded module is type '"+typeof(mod)+"' not type 'function'"); }
        mod = new mod(...args);
        if(typeof(mod)!=="object") { throw Error("Loaded module is type '"+typeof(mod)+"' not type 'object'"); }
        return mod;
        }
    catch(err) { err.message += " (loading "+pthORurl+")"; throw err; }
    }
```